Си. Вывести Х точных значащих цифр после десятичной точки искомого числа
Я решил решить задачу из e-olymp, что казалась мне лёгкой, код прикрепляется снизу, но почему-то его точность составляет 30%, даже не знаю в чём проблема, код выполняет сказанное.
Условие задачи:
Дана рациональная дробь т / п. Запишите её в виде десятичной дроби с точностью к знаков после запятой.
Входные данные:
В одной строке записано 3 числам, n, k.0 m, n ≤ 100, 0 ≤ k ≤ 1000.
Выходные данные:
Вывести к точных значащих цифр после десятичной точки искомого числа.
Примеры
Ввод  - 123
Ответ - 0.500
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    scanf("%d", &c);

    float result = (float) a / b;
    printf("%.*f", c, result);
}

В чём проблема этого кода?

Условие задачи где? Может, у вас там ввод не целых чисел или еще что... А то "доктор, у меня что-то болит, но я не скажу что...

@Harry я знаю к чему вы клоните, я не знаю что добавить к себе в сообщения, буквально написал всё про эту задачу

Мне не надо "про задачу", дайте текст задачи. Если совсем невмоготу - URL. Откуда я знаю, может, там числа могут быть нецелые, или с до 15, а вы float используете. Без точного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ. Где ТЗ? О, кажется, нашел сам. Эта задача - https://www.eolymp.com/ru/problems/11? Если да, то как вы хотите выводить 1000 цифр для float? :) Пишите длинную арифметику, деление в столбик... И, кстати, вы прикалывались или в самом деле не понимаете, что значит - точное условие задачи?

Одним циклом for :)
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int m, n, k;
    for(scanf("%d %d %d",&m,&n,&k),printf("%d.",m/n);
        k-->0;m%=n,putchar((m*=10)/n+'0'));
}


Браво 8-) . . .
